How to embed a Replit Project on Wix, so that it automatically runs, and fits the screen of the website
I tried to make an embed on Wix, but I didn't how to. I also tried to make an embed on W3 schools, which kind of worked, but it didn't run the project but instead showed the files of the project.
I was expecting it to run correctly, and show my website.
My code is:
<iframe src="https://replit.com/@Orbits/LHSCC?embed=true" width="600" height="400"></iframe>

if you open the embedded preview https://replit.com/@Orbits/LHSCC?embed=true#index.html you will see that it doesn't run the website is not being run, and instead is just showing the files, as you realised.
Unfortunately as seen here https://ask.replit.com/t/how-can-i-run-a-repl-by-its-cover-page/94590 the code can no longer be run and must instead be deployed which requires a paid account.
As a work around, you may want to look into other websites like Vercel or buying a paid accoun. https://docs.replit.com/additional-resources/embedding-repls
